# Creating collection of class that isn't table with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, poco

Is there any way I can create collection of objects that aren't table?
I mean something like -

```
class Deck
{
     [Key]
     public int DeckId { get; set; }


     [Required]
     public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }       
}
```

If I had a table for the cards it would be alright, but what will happen if I don't have a table for that class?

Comment: Why would you do this?  It would violate your separation of concerns.  If you need Deck to have cards, then use a DTO or view model, since the data concern isn't interested in cards.

Comment: Because i'm creating a card game and since there only one from each card I can't that any card will be duplicated. I have to check if the new card is already in use so I thought to create a Collection of the cards that in use. Do you have a better idea? @Maess

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In code first you mark the entry with the `NotMappedAttribute`. Depending on your configuration it should be possible to put it into a partial class.

Here's an example that filters a mapped set of related data into a specific unmapped sub set of the same data.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[NotMapped]
public ICollection<Cards> RemainingCards
{
    get
    {
        return AllCards.Where(s => s.SomeCiteria == true).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have to create a table for the cards and then I will fetch it from the Deck class by my condition?

Comment: @Videron no that's just an example. you can hard code an array of 52 cards if you like ... the important part is the `NotMappedAttribute`

Comment: but I still need it will be saved on the database. My problem is that if I will save everything on table for cards I will have to check everytime something like this - 
`return AllCards.Any(s => s.DeckId == Id && s.CardValue == Value);`
and it will check a lot of rows so I thought to minimize it by save it in list or array.

Comment: @Videron the question title says there's no table :-/